# How to track the id of draggable div id in drop function

Tags: javascript, html

I have to find the id of draggable div in drop function using javascript. Using Jquery i know how to find it. but i am stuck in one condition where id of the dragged event is necessary in drop function. In drag function I am able to get id by using  `alert("id "+obj.id)` but please help me out to find this in drop function using javascript.

Here is the code

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev, obj)
{
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
    alert("id "+obj.id)
}

function drop(ev)
{
    farea1[i] = x[0].getElementsByTagName("termTxt")[i].getAttribute("correctCat");

    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));


    i++;
    display();

    if(ev.target.id == "area1"){
        fans1[n]=farea1[k];
        k++;
        n++;
        countarea1++;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function to find the droppable id

```
$(function() {

        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).html( "Dropped in " + this.id );
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans but I am not using ui event. Please suggest in javascript. Code I have pasted above please check

Comment: add alert(ev.target.id); in drop function

Comment: by using ev.target.id i am getting the id of the text area where i have dropped the element not the id of the dragged object which I have  dragged in that area.

Comment: ok do one thing take a global variable above all your functions like var objID = ""; and in your drag function try to add this line of code objId = ev.target.id; and then in your drop function you can simply access objId variable to access the id of the dragged object

Comment: Thanks a ton!! Working now :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get that target div ID by :

```
  $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $('.display').html("Dropped in " + this.id);
        },
        over: function(event, ui) {
            $('.display').html( this.id );
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans but I am not using ui event. Please suggest in javascript. Code I have pasted above please check

Comment: try this : var target=e.target || e.srcElement; var id=target.id;

Comment: by using this i am getting the id of the text area where i have dropped the element not the id of the dragged object which I have  dragged in that area.